# Authorised Exception using access code which never expires

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook Access Token Debugger I can see I have an access token that never expires. 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

However using the Graph Explorer I get the error

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 10,
```

...
       }
    }

This was previously working, has something changed with Facebook? The only other thing that has changed is that my access to the Facebook App was removed then reinstated, so I now use a different access code.

Please could anyone advise what I need to do to resolve this issue, I previously did not need Facebook review to use this API last month.

Thanks

Edited: the login required screen when requesting a Page Access Token:
[image: login required]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to misorude for all your help. This is what worked for me:

Step 1: ask the business manager to grant the user "Manage Pages" permission on both the app and the page:

https://business.facebook.com/settings/pages/PageID?business_id=BusinessID
https://business.facebook.com/settings/apps/AppID?business_id=BusinessID

Step 2: Create the user access token (select "Get User Access Token" from the "Get Token" dropdown)

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Step 3: Check the user has access by calling your graph method using the temporary user access token

E.g. https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/PageID?fields=link%2Cpicture&access_token=UserAccessToken

E.g. https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/PageID/feed?fields=message%2Cfull_picture%2cpermalink_url%2Ccreated_time&limit=3&access_token=UserAccessToken

Step 4: Create permanent user access token
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ 
Click "Extend Access Token" at the bottom of the page and debug to reveal the token with expiry: never

Answer (score 2):

This is not about expiry of the token.

Facebook has restricted API access to the data of any public pages - you now need to get your app reviewed for the use of the feature “Page Public Content Access”, before you can use it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature#reference-PAGES_ACCESS

Without getting this reviewed, you can only access data from pages you have admin access to - but that in turn requires the use of a different kind of token then, a page access token. (You presumably used the general app access token, for your requests that have been working up until now. For that to keep working to access public page data, you need to submit for review of the feature.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have admin access, how do I use a page access token? Previously I generated a User Access Token then extended the expiry to never. When I try to generate a Page Access Token I get the message "Invalid Scopes: manage_pages". How do I enable this permission? I have full administrator rights

Comment: You need to submit your app for review, before you can use `manage_pages` permission in live mode.

Comment: I don't understand, you said "Without getting this reviewed, you can only access data from pages you have admin access to" - that's all I need, is a review still necessary?

Comment: Yes – your app’s usage of the `manage_pages` permission still needs review in this case then. There’s different stuff to review - most _permissions_ need review before you can ask normal users for them [and some of the more “potent” ones, like `manage_pages`, need review in general, before anyone can be asked for them if the app is live], _features_ like Page Public Content Access need review … You need to add whatever you are actually using to your review, and submit it for approval.

Comment: When I attempt to get a Page Access Token I get redirected to permission for Login but that info page specifically says "You do not need to submit your app if it will only be used in Development Mode by you or someone with a role on your app. Any account listed in the Roles tab in your App Dashboard, such as admins, developers, and testers, can use all permissions but will only be able to access their own data, that of test users, and test pages belonging to them." I cannot get this working even in development, why is login permission required?

Comment: I think that is a bit outdated. It used to be that users with a role in the app could be asked for any permission, reviewed or not - even when the app is in live mode. That has been changed a while ago for certain important permissions, such as `manage_pages` - even people with an app role can not be asked for that any more, when the app is in live mode. As long as you keep it in dev mode, you should be able to ask people with a role for _any_ permission though, not sure what you are currently doing wrong if that doesn’t work for you.

Comment: Please clarify: "You should be able to ask people with a role for any permission" where is this requested? I can only request formal app review: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[ID]/app-review/permissions/?business_id=[ID]

Comment: Asking for permissions happens by calling the login dialog. This has little to do with your app dashboard, this is a front-end action that requires user interaction.

Comment: Apologies I don't understand, I'm not using the login dialog. My request is for API access to the page data; "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/[PageID]?fields=link%2Cpicture&access_token=[UserAccessToken]"

Comment: Your page admin user account needs to grant your app the necessary permissions first, before you can get a page access token. And granting permissions to apps is done via the login dialog. (If you don’t want to implement login functionality within your app, you can also use Graph API Explorer to grant the permissions and get your user token there. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/explorer/ has instructions on how to use it.)

Comment: That's what I already did, I created a User Access Token with the "manage_pages" permission set but using that token I get the error on API request

Comment: What error are you talking about now? The screenshot of the login dialog that you added to your question now, does not show an _error_, but just a hint (that you will need to submit for review, before this could be used by normal users) - but that should not stop you from proceeding with the dialog.

Comment: A user token with manage_pages permission is not the same as a page access token.